# Null records in data comparison

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am building a VIEW by comparing two tables having columns namely RUN_DATE(TABLE 1) of date format and FT_Data_cut(TABLE 2 ) of date format. I need to fetch the latest data from Table 2

---

into View. My below condition is not working.

```
SELECT 
FROM "XYZ"."DATA_LAKE"."STE_INCOMING" 
WHERE FT_DATA_CUT = (
  select max(RUN_DATE) 
  from "XYZ"."OUTBOUND"."CONTROL_TABLE" 
  where release_flag = 'RELEASED' 
  and table_name='STE_INCOMING');
```

On brief checking,

```
select max(RUN_DATE) 
from "XYZ"."OUTBOUND"."CONTROL_TABLE" 
where release_flag = 'RELEASED'
and table_name='STE_INCOMING'
```

(Working fine)

My above query is working properly but I am not able to compare the two dates. It is returning **Zero** Rows in output. But we have a common date(ex- 2022-02-21) in both columns. The data type is also the same for both tables as I discussed earlier. I don't know why it is not able to compare the two dates

Comment: ok sure @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: `It is returning Null Data in output` NULL or 0 rows?

Comment: It is returning zero rows. Thanks for highlighting @LukaszSzozda

Comment: It is not working@LukaszSzozda

Comment: Yes this query (SELECT * FROM "XYZ"."DATA_LAKE"."STE_INCOMING" WHERE FT_DATA_CUT  = '2022-02-21') is working fine

Comment: It is also not working

Comment: What value does the subquery return? What happens if you use this value directly in your main query, instead of using the subquery?

Comment: What is the data type of `FT_DATA_CUT`?  If it's a string/varchar then you need to cast your sub-query date to a string/varchar in order for it to work correctly.